# How to use bootstrapFactory in DartAngular 5?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have main method:

```
Future<Null> main() async {
  final securityService = new SecurityService(new BrowserClient());
  await securityService.getObject();

  bootstrapStatic<AppComponent>(
      AppComponent,
      <dynamic>[
        provide<SecurityService>(SecurityService,
            useFactory: () => securityService, deps: []),
        provide<BrowserClient>(BrowserClient,
            useFactory: () => new BrowserClient(), deps: []),
        routerProvidersHash
      ],
      ng.initReflector as Function);
}
```

I want to rewrite it to use `bootstrapFactory`. How to do that? What should I rewrite in components with `providers: const [MyService]`?

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/934. The code docs in https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/11c05e29fafcea13e4d54f246e70402460777e94/angular/lib/src/bootstrap/run.dart contain examples. What part is unclear?

Comment: Thank you, @GünterZöchbauer! Look like it work. Is there a better way to import run.dart, without src?

Comment: If it is supposed to be used outside Angular, then it should be exported by `'package:angular/angular.dart'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I wrote this:

```
// ignore: uri_has_not_been_generated
import 'package:budget/app_component.template.dart' as ng_app;

...

// ignore: uri_has_not_been_generated
import 'main.template.dart' as ng;

@GenerateInjector(const [
  const ClassProvider<BrowserClient>(BrowserClient),
  const FactoryProvider<SecurityService>(SecurityService, getSecurityService),
  routerProvidersHash
])
final InjectorFactory appInjector = ng.appInjector$Injector;

SecurityService _securityService;
SecurityService getSecurityService() => _securityService;

Future<Null> main() async {
  _securityService = new SecurityService(new BrowserClient());
  await _securityService.getObject();

  runApp<AppComponent>(
      ng_app.AppComponentNgFactory as ComponentFactory<AppComponent>,
      createInjector: appInjector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this:

```
Client _browserClient;
Client getBrowserClient() => _browserClient;

SecurityService _securityService;
SecurityService getSecurityService() => _securityService;

Future<Null> main() async {
  _browserClient = new BrowserClient();
  _securityService = new SecurityService(_browserClient);
  await _securityService.getObject();

  bootstrapStatic(
      AppComponent,
      [
        const FactoryProvider(Client, getBrowserClient),
        const FactoryProvider(SecurityService, getSecurityService),
      ],
      ng.initReflector);
}
```

**Edit:** The above method applies till AngularDart 5.0.0-alpha+9. From 5.0.0-alpha+10 version, `runApp` function is strongly recommended instead of `bootstrapStatic`